# clould computing vs email storage

Tags: cloud

i am a complete noob to cloud computing. i read that cloud computing means storing data on a remote server rather than to store it on our hard drive. And then accessing this data whenever required. 
I can also store my data upto 10GB in yahoo or gmail. Then are these  email facilities also considered as a part of cloud? If not, then what is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, these service do count as part of a Cloud. They belong to family of Cloud services called "Software as a Service (SaaS)", cause you get complete a complete software solution (in your case - email) from the cloud (which is "cloud" of remote computers somewhere over the Internet).

There are many types of cloud services. For example:

- Infrastructure as a service: you get pure computing power - CPU cycles, Memory...
- Platform as a service: you get application platform for deploying your own applications on top of it, for example the JavaEE platform.
- Software as a service: you get a complete software solution, like Email.

The common properties for all above are:

- They are provided to you as a service by some third party over the Internet;
- Scalebility, meaning it suits your needs whether they're small or big;

More about this topic is nicely summarized in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing).